# Using NSFetchedResultController how to ensure that only 100 rows are displayed

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsfetchedresultscontroller

```
request.fetchLimit = 100;
request.fetchBatchSize = 100;
```

is it true use that function to make limit for how many rows at tableView with NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate?

but the problem is.. sometime the table will show more than 100 rows, but when I change the page and back to the table, the table will show just 100 rows, how can it be? I don't want the table can show more than 100.

thank you in advanced.

Another way to do it is to do

is to update

```
 id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.FetchController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    CalledRowCountingNotYetCallRowForSection=true;
    [self.tableViewA setBounces:YES];


    if([sectionInfo numberOfObjects]>100){
        //[Timer searchCriteriaChanged];
        CLog(@"Something Wrong This NumberOfRow: %d", [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
    }
    else{
    }
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
```

so that when numberOfObjects is bigger than 100, then the number of row becomes 100. However, that interfere with

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
```

So how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could limit the amount of available rows by overriding the **numberOfSectionsInTableView** and **numberOfRowsInSection** functions of your table view data source, returning 1 and 100, respectively.

Are you using a **SQLStore** as base for your table? According to apple documentation ( http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSFetchRequest_Class/NSFetchRequest.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSFetchRequest ), fetchLimit does only work for SQL stores.

Comment: It interfere with the updating.